# Fibonacci with recursion method

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a fibonacci function that should takes as input 3 arguments, r = the number of the output elements, 'a' the start number and 'b' the second number. fib(r,a,b)

I have done the following but something goes wrong:

```
def fib(r,a,b):
    return [[(a,b),fib(i,b,a+b)] for i in range(r)]
```

Can anyone said me where is the problem and help me to solve it?

Comment: What goes wrong? Is it hanging? Syntax error?

Comment: Side note: if this is python 2 `range(SOME_BIG_NUMBER)` will actually create a list with many numbers inside before doing anything.

Comment: What is the desired output?  As it is, even if you fix the errors,  you will get lists inside lists

Comment: the function is called fib and inside it calls fib (refers to itself)

Comment: i got that output:  [[(1, 1), 0], [(1, 1), 1], [(1, 1), [[(1, 2), 0], [(1, 2), 1]]], [(1, 1), [[(1, 2), 0], [(1, 2), 1], [(1, 2), [[(2, 3), 0], [(2, 3), 1]]]]], [(1, 1), [[(1, 2), 0], [(1, 2), 1], [(1, 2), [[(2, 3), 0], [(2, 3), 1]]], [(1, 2), [[(2, 3), 0], [(2, 3), 1], [(2, 3), [[(3, 5), 0], [(3, 5), 1]]]]]]], [(1, 1), [[(1, 2), 0], [(1, 2), 1], [(1, 2), [[(2, 3), 0], [(2, 3), 1]]], [(1, 2), [[(2, 3), 0], [(2, 3), 1], [(2, 3), [[(3, 5), 0],..

Comment: what's an "end number"?

Comment: yes, because I am trying to use recursion method.

Comment: Please change your question containing the desired and the actual output.  Putting that in comments is not such a good idea.

Comment: What are the smallest values it works for?

Comment: What output are you trying to get? I don't understand your question. Can you give the mathematical expression?

Comment: when i run the above function i want to get the following output:               [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]

Comment: The problem is you're calling the function within the list comprehension, making these recursive lists. What you want to do instead, is return a list out of the current element, prepended to the result of the next function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the function within the list comprehension, making the lists recursive. Also, you're missing a condition under which the function terminates.

Try this instead:

```
def fib(r,a,b):
    return [a] + fib(r-1,b,a+b) if r>0 else []
```

Note that this is horribly inefficient and should never be actually used.

Comment: ok i have understand, but i cant to do it like this because i can concatenate list with list not number with list. is it right?

Comment: Correct, that's why you concatenate a list with a list here! `a` is a number, but `[a]` is a list!